# Static lambdas in python

Tags: python, lambda, static-methods

I have class in python like this

```
 import numpy as np
 class BackPropogationNetwork:
        # Static lambdas
        sigmoid = lambda x : 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
        sigmoid_prime = lambda sigmoid: sigmoid(1-sigmoid)
```

and this is the contructor

```
 def __init__(self):
    self.some_attr = self.sigmoid(2)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

If I call like this

```
self.some_attr = ClassName.sigmoid()
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with BackPropogationNetwork instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Comment: If you define the `lambda`s inside the class definition, they're the same as any other instance method - you need the `self` argument, and can't call them on the class. Why are you using `lambda` anyway? If you want a `@classmethod`, write one.

Comment: What about `ClassName.sigmoid(2)`?

Comment: use `def` instead. `lambda` in python is a broken feature and it doesn't provide extra power as one in other languages. then use `@staticmethod` descriptor. `self.` implies self to be a parameter too. so you are passing two parameters in.

Comment: I want the functional approach? Like in lisp or haskell

Answer (score 9):

You need to wrap the lambdas in [`staticmethod` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
class BackPropogationNetwork:
    sigmoid = staticmethod(lambda x : 1/(1+np.exp(-x)))
    sigmoid_prime = staticmethod(lambda sigmoid: sigmoid(1-sigmoid))
```

`lambda` expressions still produce function objects, just using different (limited) syntax. The same rules apply as defining functions in a class; if you want it to be a static method then you still need to wrap them.

Comment: i think `staticmethod` would be more appropriate

Comment: Yes, When I said `classmethod ` it gave `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: @Javier: yup, too much PHP/Hack work today (`static` in PHP is `classmethod` in Python).

Comment: @Goutam because a `classmethod` requires a `cls` argument, the class itself, whereas a `staticmethod` doesn't require any instance/class argument.

Comment: Actually what are the differences between `staticmethod()`,`classmethod()` and what the code I have written? I mean in python

Comment: @Goutam: normal methods get a `self` argument with the object's instance; `classmethods` get a `cls` argument with the class, `staticmethods` have no added argument.

Comment: If I want to make that a class method what should I do?

Comment: At class definition time, any method not specifically typed is assumed to be a normal method, and gets a `self` argument.  the `classmethod` and `staticmethod` decorators change this.

Answer (score 3):

So your sigmoid function is kinda independent of the class, it would make sense to keep it outside, unless:

- you want to not pollute the namespace of the module
- you want to increase the discoverability of the function
- you want this method to me overwritten.
  Let's assume you have made up your mind and nothing can change it, well in that case you can do this.
  When you call a method like `self.method()` python passes the the first argument to the funtion the instance self, so either you can make you lambda like this: `sigmoid = lambda self, x : 1/(1+np.exp(-x))`
  or you can do what others have suggested like make it a staticmethod, since staticmethod is a decorator, (function that takes a function) it can be called like this

  ```
  In [1]: class A:
     ...:     s = staticmethod(lambda x: x)
     ...:     def a(self):
     ...:         print self.s(10)
     ...:

  In [2]: f = A()

  In [3]: f.a()
  10
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your two sigmoid's are not class methods. This means when you call them they expect Class as the implicit first argument.

This error

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

occurs on this call

```
self.some_attr = self.sigmoid(2)
```

because Class instance object is being passed implicitly along with the int 2. But your sigmoid is defined to accept only one argument.

And I don't think you will get this error

```
TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with BackPropogationNetwork instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

with this call

```
self.some_attr = ClassName.sigmoid()
```

The error you should get should be something like.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'type'
```

May be you made a copy paste error while typing the question.