# How to run Python3 program which uses lambda from the Bash

Tags: python, bash

In Python program I have among others a class which allows colouring text:

```
class style():
    BLACK = lambda x: '\033[30m' + str(x)
    RED = lambda x: '\033[31m' + str(x)
    GREEN = lambda x: '\033[32m' + str(x)
    YELLOW = lambda x: '\033[33m' + str(x)
    BLUE = lambda x: '\033[34m' + str(x)
    MAGENTA = lambda x: '\033[35m' + str(x)
    CYAN = lambda x: '\033[36m' + str(x)
    WHITE = lambda x: '\033[37m' + str(x)
    UNDERLINE = lambda x: '\033[4m' + str(x)
    RESET = lambda x: '\033[0m' + str(x)
```

Exemplary calling:

```
print(style.UNDERLINE('ATTACHMENT TEST') + style.RESET(''))
```

Now I want to run that Python3 program from the Bash. 
I tried:

- in Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

python Annotation\ test/Annotation_test.py
#or 
./Annotation\ test/Annotation_test.py
```

- in Python3 program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

But when I run my script, Bash says that:

```
print(style.UNDERLINE('ATTACHMENT TEST') + style.RESET(''))
TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with style instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Although that program in the PyCharm works completely fine. Why Bash has a problem with that? 
And how can I fix that? Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Relevant? [Static lambdas in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307012/static-lambdas-in-python)

Comment: I don't see why PyCharm would accept this. `bash` has nothing to do with it; `python` is the program interpreting the code, not `bash`.

Comment: @chepner please make tab in style() body, my formatting was bad. It works in PyCharm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bash most probably uses python 2 as it's default and the pycharm console uses python 3, that's why you're only seeing the error in bash.

Try setting python 3 as the default python for your system. You can also run this file only with python 3 by running the following:

```
python3  Annotation\ test/Annotation_test.py
```

or

```
py -3 Annotation\ test/Annotation_test.py
```

Comment: I suppose that is very probable but now I have problem with cv2 library.  `import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`  In Bash -Python2 and Pycharm - Python3 it is properly imported

Comment: you can install the package for python 3 using the following command:                          py -3 -m pip install opencv-python